# Displaying divs when the ones before are full with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to display divs when the div contents before is full of words and continue to fill this new div with the rest of the words.

I don't know how to do it. In fact, in the code below I wrote that the div is displayed on click of a button. I also can't set the "fill-action" explained above.

The limit of the words in one div has to be settable from the code.

For example, if I set the limit to two words and there are only two words to be displayed, the second div shouldn't be created.

But If there are four words to be displayed and the limit is still on two words,
the second div has to be created and has to be filled with the third and fourth words.

Another problem is that if I write HTML text (e.g. `<font color="#ff0000">`), the tags (e.g. `<font`) shouldn't be considered as a word.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0uz6o13/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="faketxt" contenteditable>Write Here</div>
<button id='btn'>OK</button>
<div id='casella' class='fakes'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#faketxt {
-moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
-webkit-appearance: textarea;
border: 1px solid gray;
height: 28px;
overflow: auto;
padding: 2px;
resize: both;
width: 400px;
}

#casella{
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.fakes{
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var primo = document.getElementById('faketxt');
  var secondo = document.getElementById('casella');
  secondo.innerHTML = primo.innerHTML;
  var myDiv = $('#casella');
  myDiv.text(myDiv.text().substring(0,5)) //This is when the div is "full"
});

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {
var ok = true;

 if (ok === true) {
      var div = document.createElement('div');

      div.className = 'fakes';       

   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
  }
};
```

In this case I set that the div is full when there are 5 letters, so the word "*Here*" has to be displayed in the second div...
Is this possible?
I can't figure it out.

Comment: What should happen in the event of the word "herald"? Should there be two elements, or should the word remain in one container? What about white-space, should that fall between the elements with the words/letters, or should a white-space count as a letter/character itself?

Comment: @DavidThomas oh, yes. You're rigt. I think is better that the word remain in one container... And I think that white-space should not count as a letter itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to separate the words (by spaces) and add a *div* container for each word using [Array.foreach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Also with this approach, use [Array.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to set the text of the *myDiv* element (i.e. with `id="casella"`) to the first word.

#### UPDATE:

Per the changing requirements, the code below now has a number input for the word limit. It then strips HTML codes (using the HTML entities) using a regular expression and then uses a counter to add words to newly created *div* elements. The functionality to create a new *div* element has been abstracted to the function *createdDiv()*.

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var primo = document.getElementById('faketxt');
  var wordLimit = $('#wordLimit').val();
  //strip html characters from string and use a regular expression 
  //to split based on white-space characters
  var words = primo.innerHTML.replace(/(&lt;([^&gt;]+)&gt;)/ig,"").split(/\s/);
  if (words.length) {
    var count = 0;
    var div = createDiv();
    words.forEach(function(word) {
      if (++count > wordLimit) {
        count = 0; //reset counter
        div = createDiv();
      }
      if (div.innerHTML) {
        div.append(' ');
      }
      div.append(word);
    });
  }
});

function createDiv() {
  div = document.createElement('div'); //could use jQuery $('div') instead
  div.className = 'fakes';
  document.body.append(div);
  return div;
}
```

```css
#faketxt {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 28px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  resize: both;
  width: 400px;
}
#casella {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.fakes {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Word Limit:
  <input type="number" id="wordLimit" value="1" />
</div>
<div id="faketxt" contenteditable>Write Here</div>
<button id='btn'>OK</button>
```

Comment: If the words are for example "Write Here Guys", it doesn't create the third div with the word "Guys" in it. How can it be done? Thank you very much!

Comment: Wait, the last edit I think was good. Because I need to set how many words can stay in a div...

Comment: Please update the explanation of your question to include all details of how many words should be placed in a div.

Answer (score 2):

for displaying divs at right position

css:

```
.fakes{
   width: 150px;
   height: 300px;
   font-size: 10px;
   border-style: solid;
   display : inline-block;
 }

 #boxes{
   display : flex;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div id="faketxt" contenteditable>Write Here</div>
<button id='btn'>OK</button><br>
<div id="boxes">
  <div id='casella' class='fakes'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, It displays all the text in the first div. look: https://jsfiddle.net/c0uz6o13/2/

Comment: It appears you modified the jQuery click handler, not the *onclick* callback - see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxny8bqm/) for those changes

Comment: @NiccolòGuidi sam's answer works better :P sry didnt read the last 2 lines of ur question...
i updated my reply for div positioning...

Comment: @NiccolòGuidi u changed html and css both? coz its working on ur jsfiddle

Comment: Yes, it doesn't display the divs orizontally

Comment: @NiccolòGuidi https://jsfiddle.net/s4zu270g/ old code :) but right positioned divs ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
 var myDiv = $('#casella');
 var primo = document.getElementById('faketxt');
 var secondo = document.getElementById('casella');

 $('#btn').click(function() { 

   var inputArray = primo.innerHTML.split(" ");

   var secDivContent = '';

   if(inputArray[0].length > 5 || primo.innerHTML.length > 5 ) {
     secDivContent = primo.innerHTML.substr(5);         
   }    

  var div = document.createElement('div');

  div.className = 'fakes'; 
  div.innerHTML = secDivContent;
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);

});
```

Comment: check out that code, just a quick logic I come up with